# Selecting column values base on a priority reference table?

Tags: sql, database, netezza

I want to create a select query which will select values for each column based on a priority set in a reference table. In the case where there are more than one values for a column, it will select the most recent using the date field.

Example:

Customer Table:

```
CustomerID   customerName   CustomerEmail    monthDate    SourceID
1            Michael        NULL             1/1/2017     4
2            Sarah          Sarah@email.com  2/1/2017     2
3            Dave           Dave@no.com      3/1/2017     1
4            Sal            Sal@mail.com     4/1/2017     4
4            Sally          Sall@emai.com    5/1/2017     4
1            Mike S         Mike.s@em.com    5/1/2017     3
```

Reference Table:

```
SourceID   Priority
1          2
2          3
3          4
4          1
```

4My select query would show:

```
CustomerID   customerName   CustomerEmail
1            Michael        Mike.s@em.com
2            Sarah          Sarah@email.com
3            Dave           Dave@no.com
4            Sally          Sall@emai.com
```

So where a column has a NULL value it will populate with the highest priority value. Where there are two values with the same priority it will select the one with the most recent date. This must be selected at a column level to get the most up to date value for every field.

Any help or a point in the right direction would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a `join` to bring the tables together and get the priority.  Then you can use `row_number()` to select the "first" for each customer:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by c.customerid
                                order by r.priority desc, monthdate desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from customer c join
           reference r
           on c.sourceid = r.sourceid
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Won't this just select the whole row with the highest 'priority'. I need this to work at a column level. So for example if there are 4 rows for one customer (rows 1,2,3 and 4) it could pick the name from row 1, the email from row 2, the phone number from row 3 and so on?